# Trouble adding existing user to existing group in ubuntu

Tags: users, group

I was trying to add a user called bill to www group

```
useradd -G www bill
```

It gives me error

```
UX: useradd: ERROR: bill is already in use.  Choose another.
```

I checked if this user already in the group www by typing this command

```
group bill
```

it resulted

```
bill:bill
```

Which means he is not in www group but still i keep getting the error

Later I realized from [this link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-add-user-to-group/) that there are different commands to add existing user to existing group and adding a new user to new group. So I tries this command to add bill (an existing user) to www (an existing group)

```
usermod -a -G www bill
```

It gives me syntax error

```
UX: usermod: ERROR: Invalid syntax.
usage:  usermod -u uid [-o] | -g group | -G group[[,group]...] |
                -d dir [-m] | -s shell | -c comment |
                -l new_logname | -f inactive | -e expire |
                -A authorization [, authorization ...] | -K key=value ... |
                -P profile [, profile ...] | -R role [, role ...] login
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options: the `usermod` you wrote is correct, but the implementation you use does not handle `-a`. Just get rid of it and try again.

The second option is to use `adduser` from the `adduser` package. Then you will be able to write `adduser username groupname`. After logging out (and back in) you will have access to that group.

Comment: "-bash: adduser: command not found"

Comment: Maybe you don't have it installed: `apt-get install adduser`

Comment: moreover, the `usermod` you typed seems correct to me. It fails becuase the ubuntu usermod seems to ignore option `-a`. Could you try without using it?

Comment: surprisingly working :) which didnt worked yesterday. can you update the answer with this because your answer leading to other issues?